# Need to count the number of lines in my ressources files over all the solutions

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, resx

Hello i would like to count the number of ressources i get in my solutions.

My solutions have 29 projects and over 500 ressources files. It's there a code example i can run or a tool in VS 2010 i can use to count my ressource ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to count lines or resources?

Comment: Why do you want to count lines of XML?

Comment: It's not the line, of xml but the line of ressources in my resx file, need to know the total ressources key in my application.

Comment: You need to learn what `line` means.

Comment: Sorry .. my english is not very good ... i do my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the "calculate code metrics" functionality built into visual studio 2008 and 2010?  This will give you the line counts (among a lot of other cool things) in your projects.

You can read a short blog post about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/10/27/how-to-count-the-lines-of-code-loc-in-your-application-using-visual-studio.aspx).

You can also find it on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx).